# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') in react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to create a simple web application which lists products from fakestore api using REACT REDUX. But react is throwing the error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')".

productListing.jsx

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { setProducts } from '../redux/actions/productActions';
import ProductComponent from './ProductComponent';

const ProductListing = () => {
    // const products = useSelector((state) => state.allProducts.products);
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const fetchProducts = async () => {
        const response = await axios
          .get("https://fakestoreapi.com/products")
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log("Err: ", err);
          });
        dispatch(setProducts(response.data));
        console.log(response.data)

      };
    

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchProducts()
        },[])
    // console.log("Products :" , products)

    return (
        <div className="ui grid container">
            <ProductComponent />
        </div>
    );
};

export default ProductListing;
```

The above component is responsible for api call from fakestoreapi and updating the redux store.

In the following component named "productComponent.jsx" i tried to list the products from the redux store using map method which is as follows :

```js
import React from 'react'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

const ProductComponent = () => {
    const pdts = useSelector((state) => state.allProducts.products);

    // console.log(typeof(pdts))


    console.log("Products",pdts)
    const renderList = pdts.map((pdt) => {

        // const { id, title, image, price, category } = pdt;
        return(
            <div className="four column wide" key={pdt.id}>
            <div className="ui link cards">
                <div className="card">
                    <div className="image">
                        <img src={pdt.image} alt={pdt.title}  />
                    </div>
                    <div className="content">
                        <div className="header">{pdt.title}</div>
                        <div className="meta price">$ {pdt.price}</div>
                        <div className="meta">{pdt.category}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        )
    })

    
    return(
        <>{renderList}</>
        // <>gbdf</>
    )
    
}

export default ProductComponent
```

But React is throwing the folowing error :
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFwuL.png)

when i consoled the products object it shows undefined. But after I commented renderlist and again consoled the products object it consoled two time with the first one being undefined and second one printing the correct object with values. At this point of time I uncommented the render list, now the react is listing the products but when i again reload the page it consoles undefined value for two times.

Answer (score 0):

`Pdts` is undefined in the first render. Hence cant be mapped.
Try this
`pdts?.map()`
It's known as [Optional Chaining.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)